# when i add the data to the table price and item undefined using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a simple inventory control system using jQuery and php. When I select item it ask the qty. After entering the qty then click add button all details need to be  added to the  table. But only qty added other details are not added. I attached the screen shot image below. and code below what i tried so far.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URt0u.jpg)

**Form**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="list-group-item list-group-tem-action active">Item</div>
            <div class="panel-body bg-dark" style="color: white">
                <form id="frm-project">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div >
                            <img class="photo" id="Chocolate" src="images/chocolate-ice.jpg" width="100" height="100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                            <b>Chocolate</b>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/mango.jpg" width="100" height="100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                            <b>Mango</b>
                        </div>
                        <div  >
                            <img class="photo" id="Venila" src="images/venila.jpg" width="100" height="100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                            <b>Venila</b>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <img class="photo" id="Strawberry" src="images/sww.jpg" width="100" height="100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                            <b>Strawberry</b>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img class="photo" id="MixFruit" src="images/mixfruit.jpg" width="100" height="100" >
                            <b>MixFruit</b>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </form>
            <!-- missing div -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Table**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="list-group-item list-group-tem-action active">AddProducts</div>
        <table id="tbl-item" class="table table-dark table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                    <th>Item</th>

                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            <!-- missing </thead> -->
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**bootsstrip Model click click the img ask the qty**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <label>Qty</label>
                <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" placeholder="Qty">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="ADD" onclick="add()">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reset" name="reset" id="reset" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

after the enter the qty click add button data need to added the table
**jQuery**

```
    function add()
    {
        var price = null;
        var item;

        $(".photo#Chocolate").click(function ()
        {
            item = "Chocolate";
            price =56;
        });

        $(".photo#Venila").click(function ()
        {
            alert("Venila");
        });

        var qty = $('#qty').val();
        tot = qty * price;
        var table1 =
            "<tr>" +
            "<td><button type='button' name='record' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='deleterow(this)'>Delete </td>" +
            "<td>" + item + "</td>" +
            "<td>" +  price +  "</td>" +
            "<td>" +  qty +  "</td>" +
            "<td>" +  tot +  "</td>" +
            "</tr>" ;
        total += Number(tot);
        $('#total').val(total);
        $("table tbody").append(table1);
    }
```

Comment: You really need to start using better markup, it will help you when debugging as there are currently missing elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are only showing javascript and html in your code.

Usually a web-application will save data to a database (e.g. MySQL) on the server. Otherwise your data is only stored in the user's browser and will be lost.

From your question it sounds like you will be using PHP for that part (Persistence).

You will need the javascript/jquery to send the data to your php script. In your case you'll want to use something like jquery [post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Your PHP script will then take the input, validate and save it to your database.

The basic idea works like this.

Your html page contains some javascript/jquery that can send/receive data from the server. For sending you would use something like the following.

```
 $.post('myserver/myapp/submit.php',$('#frm-project').serialize());
```

At the moment, your form doesn't really contain any input fields. You will want something like

Your server will either save (PUT/POST) or send data back to your web-page (GET)
Your `submit.php` would contain some code to deal with the data.

```
 ....
 // set up your database connection, etc.
 // $db = mysqli(.....);
 ....

 $mixFruitQty = $_POST['MixFruit'];
 //sanitize your input ! just showing small example of what you might do
 $mixFruitQty = intval($mixFruitQty)
 // save to database
 $db->query("UPDATE myDBTable SET qty = {$mixFruitQty} WHERE id = 'MixFruit'";
 ...
```

Comment: sir i don't save data into the database i just need if click the image select image text need to display using jquery

Comment: above code is working only display Chocolate if i click Velila also sir